# Excel formula to get week number in month (having Monday)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Using excel formula I need to get week number in month from a given date. But, the condition is it should have Monday in it. Monday through Sunday is the work days.

I have tried this:

[image]

But, week number is given as 5, where as it should be 4 because 1st November 2013 was Friday, so it would be calculated in October's last week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If week 1 always starts on the first `Monday` of the month try this formula for week number

`=INT((6+DAY(A1+1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)))/7)`

That gets the week number from the date in A1 with no intermediate calculations - if you want to use your "Monday's date" in B1 you can use this version

`=INT((DAY(B1)+6)/7)`

Comment: Thx finally found what i needed.

Comment: Great formula. Can you explain the logic used to create a number that can be divided by 7?

Answer (score 8):

[Jonathan from the ExcelCentral forums suggests](http://forums.excelcentral.com/index.php?/topic/397-excel-formula-to-get-week-of-month/):

> ```
> =WEEKNUM(A1,2)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),2)+1
> ```
>
> This formula extracts the week of the year [...] and then subtracts it from the week of the first day in the
>   month to get the week of the month.   You can change the day that
>   weeks begin by changing the second argument of both WEEKNUM functions
>   (set to 2 [for Monday] in the above example). For weeks beginning on Sunday, use:
>
> ```
> =WEEKNUM(A1,1)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),1)+1
> ```
>
> For weeks beginning on Tuesday, use:
>
> ```
> =WEEKNUM(A1,12)-WEEKNUM(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1),12)+1
> ```
>
> etc.

I like it better because it's using the built in week calculation functionality of Excel ([WEEKNUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-036e4d0c-3d68-44b5-bd38-59b881b36047)).

Comment: Thank you! very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Finding of week number for each date of a month (considering Monday as beginning of the week)

Keep the first date of month contant `$B$13`

```
=WEEKNUM(B18,2)-WEEKNUM($B$13,2)+1
```

`WEEKNUM(B18,2)` - returns the week number of the date mentioned in cell `B18`

`WEEKNUM($B$13,2)` - returns the week number of the 1st date of month in cell `B13`