# Most efficient and easiest way in Excel VBA to classify date as week

Tags: vba, excel

I have one column that should either say Week 1, Week 2, Week 3, or Week 4.

I want to use VBA to enter the week based on what date is being looked at in a textfile...

```
For Example:

12/19/2013
12/01/2013
12/08/2013
12/26/2013
```

The output in Excel should be:

```
Week 3
Week 1
Week 2
Week 4
```

I am thinking of 4 if statements after using Split on the "/" and then converting the string to a number so it can be compared by an if statement but if I have days like "01" or "03", days starting with 0, wouldn't that cause problems in the if statements comparison?

Is there an easy way to do this in VBA?

Comment: I would do something like this: `MsgBox 1 + DateDiff("ww", DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), Date)`. Is it what you need?

Comment: @simoco, the question you answered yesterday for me worked fine but it took 4 columns and I need to use only 3 columns strictly because I am trying to edit someone's excel file and it breaks if I use 4 columns so that is why this one column I am trying to do through VBA to keep it at 3 columns

Comment: user3438716, sorry my bad - it was wrong screenshot - last column is not required - you can delete it (it's odd).

Comment: @simoco given Dim Date as String= 12/01/2013, I need to output whether the day of the month is Week 1, Week 2, Week 3, Week 4

Comment: use this one: 1) `Dim myDate as Date` 2) `myDate = DateValue("12/01/2013")` and then `MsgBox "Week " & (1 + DateDiff("ww", DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate), 1), myDate))`. Let me know if it helps

Comment: @simoco yes! That worked! THANK YOU! I LOVE YOU! Can you recommend a good for VBA + Excel? Id love to learn more about this because I didn't think Excel was that powerful until I started using VBA with it.

Comment: Also, please answer so I can accept your solution

Comment: I love this one: http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118490398.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments this one works:

```
Dim myDate as Date
myDate = DateValue("12/01/2013") 
MsgBox "Week " & (1 + DateDiff("ww", DateSerial(Year(myDate), Month(myDate), 1), myDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in formula function for this.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/weeknum-HP005209337.aspx

```
=weeknum(A1)
```

Comment: I think that just gives you what week of the year you are looking at in the date....That isn't what I want...I want what week of the MONTH... A month is usually separated in 4 weeks while a YEAR can have 20+ weeks....

Comment: Then take the MOD of the weeknumber to divide into weeks - eg `=MOD(WEEKNUM(A1)-1,4)+1` - also see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620712/excel-formula-to-get-week-number-in-month-having-monday