# Text followed by Week number of the month

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to crack how to get static text "WEEK" followed by the current week number of the month (as of 4/18/18 that is 3). This is for Range `rngColK`. Which property will show the week number of the month? `Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now)` doesn't seem to do that and I don't know if it's allowed to be added after static text "WEEK".

For Range `rngColJ`,this one is kind of off the main topic, I'm getting the right output I just need it all uppercase, and using two sections ";>" in `Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "MMMM;>"` doesn't do that. Is the syntax incorrect?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Fill in Date.
Dim rngColG As Range
Dim rngColJ As Range
Dim rngColK As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set rngColG = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 6

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not rngColG Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rng In rngColG
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Date - Weekday(Date, 3)
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mmmm d, yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End If

Set rngColJ = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 9

If Not rngColJ Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rng In rngColJ
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "MMMM;>"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End If

Set rngColK = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 10

If Not rngColK Is Nothing Then
    For Each Rng In rngColK
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = "WEEK" &" "& Int((6 + 
            Day(Date + 1 - Weekday(Date - 1))) / 7)
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If

    Next
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps :Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = "WEEK " & 
Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now)

Comment: Yup that works, but `Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now)` returns "16" which is the current week number of the year. Any idea how to get the week number of the current month??

Comment: It depends on how you define the first week of the month.

Comment: Starting with the first monday of the month.

Comment: So you want **Monday** to be the first day of the week?

Comment: Yes, this makes this week the 3rd week of the month. If you look at May, May 7th would be the first week of that month starting with Monday.

Comment: Please see barry's answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620712/excel-formula-to-get-week-number-in-month-having-monday

Answer (score 0):

Changed `Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now)` for `Int((6 + Day(Date + 1 - Weekday(Date - 1))) / 7)` to correctly output current week number of the month starting with **Monday**.